# What are I/O threads in Netty?

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

I read [***the article***](http://netty.io/wiki/thread-model.html) about thread model in [Netty](http://netty.io/wiki/thread-model.html) and have a question about the `IO` in Netty. Consider the following `ServerBootstrap` declaration:

```
NioEventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(16)
new ServerBootstrap()
.childHandler(
     new ChannelInitializer<Channel> {
          override def initChannel(ch: Channel) = ch.pipeline()
            .addLast(new ChannelDuplexHandler)   // Without specifying event-loop-group
            .addLast(workerGroup, new HttpRequestDecoder()) //event group specified
    }
```

As far as I understood the `ChannelDuplexHandler` will be invoked from IO-threads directly.

The question is how can I configure the `IO`-threads (change the number of IO-threads, maybe override the IO-thread to define my custom interrupt behavior)?

Can I make my event loop group to be an IO-group. I mean

```
NioEventLoopGroup myIoGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(16); 
                              // Is it possible to make it IO-group?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit confused by your question so I hope this answers it.... The threads that are used by the `EventLoopGroup` are "IO-threads" and the number you pass in are the numbers of "IO-threads" you want to use. Each of these threads will handle 0-n Channels. To increase the number of IO-threads you would specify a different number then "16" here.

Only one "IO-thread" will be used per Channel. If you want to ensure a `ChannelHandler` will be offloaded from the IO-thread you would usually create a `DefaultEventExecutorGroup` and specify it when you add the `ChannelHandler`. The `EventExecutorGroup` should be shared between different `Channel` instance to make the best use of threads tho.

Something like this:

```
NioEventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(16)        
EventExecutorGroup executorGroup = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(numberOfThreads);
new ServerBootstrap()
    .childHandler(
         new ChannelInitializer<Channel> {
             override def initChannel(ch: Channel) = ch.pipeline()
                 .addLast(new ChannelDuplexHandler)   // Without specifying event-loop-group
                 .addLast(executorGroup, new HttpRequestDecoder()) 
}
```